# How to read specific column of one excel and write it to specific column of another excel file in python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have 2 excel file and I want to read a specific column from file1 and write that whole column to file2's specific column without changing other columns and rows.

As of now I am able to read specific column from file1 using pandas but not able to add that column to specific column of file2.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx")
name_df=df1["name"]

df2=pd.read_excel("file2.xlsx")
name2_df=df2["name"]
df3=name2_df.append(name_df, ignore_index=True)
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',engine="xlsxwriter")
df3.to_excel(writer,"Sheet1",index=False)
writer.save()
```

Expected result should be names of file1 added to names of file2 and everything remains same but this code giving me only names.

File 1
[image: File 1 looks like this]

File 2
[image: File 2 looks like this]

Desired Output
[image: My Desired Output]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that file2 won't always be blank, am I right? If it is always blank than you might as well just take the Name column and add the other blank columns.

I'm also assuming that you column headers are named exactly as you have them in the sample data not as they are in your code (they don't match!)

```py
frames = [pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx")\
                       .rename(columns={'Name':'NAME'})['NAME']),
         pd.read_excel("file2.xlsx")]

df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df3
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',engine="xlsxwriter")
df3.to_excel(writer,"Sheet1",index=False)
writer.save()
```

**I used the following DataFrames in my test:**

```py
frames =[pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
        'ID':[123,3445],
        'Name':['Demo','Demo1'],
        'age':[23,45],
        'Gender':['M','F']
        }).rename(columns={'Name':'NAME'})['NAME']),

         pd.DataFrame( {
              'Emp No':[1],
              'DOB':['2080-01-01'],
              'NAME':['Demo2'],
              'DEPT':['Finance']})]
```

**Results:**

```
      DEPT         DOB  Emp No   NAME
0      NaN         NaN     NaN   Demo
1      NaN         NaN     NaN  Demo1
0  Finance  2080-01-01     1.0  Demo2
```

Comment: @RibhujeetDas I've edit my answer to reflect the desired outcome, however I'm not sure if you sample data is what you meant it to be.  It creates several more questions.  In the sample data you 'NAME' and 'Name', but your code doesn't reflect that.  Also, why is there no data in file2?  Is that always going to be the case.  If so my solution above will work but it's overkill when you could just add the blank columns and remove the ones you don't need.